# Can't query data using flask framework pymysql

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

Under the python flask framework, data cannot be queried using pymysql:

```
def sql_query (commit_ip):
    with db.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "select client_ip, result, date_time from ipset where client_ip = 'commit_ip'"
        cursor.execute (sql)
        dict_ipset = cursor.fetchall ()
        return dict_ipset
```

The variable commit_ip can be queried only after it is replaced with a specific IP. The same is true for date_time. The data type of client_ip is char (15). How should this sql be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass variable values as a tuple as second parameter to execute. Example from [PyMySql's doc](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html):

```
    sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
```

So for you it  would be:

```
    sql = "select client_ip, result, date_time from ipset where client_ip = %s"
    cursor.execute(sql, (commit_ip,))
```

Comment: Thank you, man! I saw that  PyMySql's doc, but there have a ''  as you know ,so I made a mistake。